# Why are there 2 ways to handle configuration?

Tags: 8

In Drupal when we are working with read-only config we use

```
$page_cache = \Drupal::config('system.performance')->get('cache.page');
```

Why this static call for read-only object?

and when we use working with a config where both read and write is possible. we use this service 'config.factory'

```
$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('system.performance');
$config->set('cache.page', ['enabled' => 1, 'max_age' => 5]);
```

what leads to this design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This change record explains it all: [Configuration objects by default are immutable.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2407153)

> `ConfigFactoryInterface::get()` no longer returns configuration
>   objects that can be saved. This is to ensure that configuration
>   overrides do not get into active configuration. Configuration
>   overrides are, for example, global overrides set in `settings.php` or
>   translations provided by the locale module. If you need to get a
>   configuration object that can be saved, use
>   `ConfigFactoryInterface::getEditable()`. Objects returned by that
>   method will not have overrides applied.
>
> #### Previously
>
> ```
> // Just get the site name (with overrides).
> $site_name = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name');
>
> // Set the site name.
> \Drupal::config('system.site')->set('name', 'My fantastic site')->save();
> ```
>
> #### Now
>
> ```
> // Just get the site name (with overrides, same as before).
> $site_name = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name');
>
> // Set the site name.
> \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('system.site')->set('name', 'My fantastic site')->save();
> ```

Are you also/alternatively asking why there's a `Drupal::config` method, but not a `Drupal::configFactory` method, i.e. why do you have to use the generic `Drupal::service` method for the second one?

If so, that's simply because the shortcut methods exposed on the `Drupal` class are for the most regularly used services. The `config` service is used in procedural code a lot more than `config.factory`, so there's no shortcut method for it. There are hundreds (thousands?) of services throughout the system so providing a method for each would be overkill

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything, also you resolved my confusion on static call vs service call. Now everything makes more sense !!